# Отсутствие шаблона Xamarin.Forms .NET Standard при создании проекта

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

[image: Скриншот]

Необходимо создать проект Xamarin.Forms, используя стратегию с .NET Standard Library, однако Visual Studio предлагает только PCL, которая не подходит из-за отсутствия в ней пространства имён System.Net.Sockets. Обновление Visual Studio не помогло. Можно ли как-то решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас старая версия Visual Studio. Установите последнюю версию и тогда все наладится.

[image: отображение версии студии]

...

[image: отображение шаблонов]